# How do I set it so that everyone uses the /bin/bash shell?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell

It doesn't seem to work for some reason if I do this in /etc/profile:

```
export SHELL="/bin/bash/"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chsh $USER` command changes users' shell.

If you want to change them all at once, you can modify the `/etc/passwd` file.

You don't want a trailing slash when attempting to execute a binary file.

Comment: Editing the passwd file directly can cause some issues.  Use the command `vipw -s` if you're going to do this.

Comment: You can't pipe sed through vipw.

Comment: Well it's not too hard to replace strings in vim.  I wouldn't risk passwd/shadow corruption.

Comment: You have a good point, I don't disagree.  As a side note, the shadow file doesn't store the shell.  =)

Answer (score 1):

To set the default shell when you create a new user, it depends how you create new users. For `useradd` in Linux (Ubuntu, at least), edit `/etc/default/useradd` and change the `SHELL` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's universal across Linux distros, but in most Unix implementations the file `/etc/shells` lists the shells that users can choose from.  So if you don't want the users to be able to use `chsh` to change to something else, make sure `bash` is the only shell listed there.

Comment: /etc/shells also has other uses; in many ftpd implementations, /etc/shells is consulted to see if the user has a 'valid' shell.  (this allows you to set their shell to /bin/false, but add it to /etc/shells, so they can use ftp, but not get a shell.)